# Heroku and LiveReload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, guard

In development I'm running guard with `liveReload`. To make it run I had to add this lines to `config.ru` file:

```
require 'rack-livereload'
use Rack::LiveReload
```

before the line `run Habrablog::Application`. Without these lines `LiveReload` doesn't work for me.

The gems `guard-livereload` and `rack-livereload` are in the develpment group of Gemfile.

But when i'm pushing to heroku server i've got a message:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
 3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': 
  no such file to load -- rack-livereload (LoadError)
```

Obviously it's because of `livereload`, how to eliminate the `livereload` configuration from production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to add anything to your config.ru file (that's just for Sinatra).

Neither of the gem install guides mention this for Rails, the rack-reload settings go in config/environments/development.rb

https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/

https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload/

Comment: LiveReload doesn't work without these lines for me :), but the question is about how to change config.ru file in production mode.